# How to skiprows across two different ranges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to isolate a data set that that is in the middle of a cvs file, but I don't know how.

I've tried

```
data_df_2 = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv', skiprows=range(1:8,21:114)
```

and

```
data_df_2 = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv', skiprows=range(1,8), skiprows=range(21,114)
```

and neither of them work. What is the correct way to approach my problem?

Comment: what is the defining feature of that row(s)? is it a word or a number. we could use a lambda to pick it out. more details about it could help

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Are you trying to skip rows 1-8 and 21-114, but read everything else? Or are trying to only read in rows 9-20 and your file is 114 lines long?

Answer (score 5):

The [`pandas.read_csv doc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) states that `skiprows` need to be list-like, int or callable. Therefore, you can create a list comprehension to generate the ranges that you want to exclude.

```
pd.read_csv('data_set.csv', skiprows=([i for i in range(1, 8)] + [j for j in range(21, 114)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed your values for easy display purposes, but concept is the same.

```
skip_1 = list(range(1, 8, 1))
skip_2 = list(range(12, 15, 1))
skip_idxs_list = skip_1 + skip_2
df_slice = df.iloc[~df.index.isin(skip_idxs_list)]
df_slice.head(20)
```

[image]